# add wp_editor to custom_meta_box

Tags: metabox, wp-editor

Can please anyone help? I created custom meta boxes, two of them are in textarea.
This is what i have:

```
array(
        'label'=> 'Ingredients',
        'desc'  => 'List of ingrediends',
        'id'    => $prefix.'ingrediends',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
    ),
        array(
        'label'=> 'Directions',
        'desc'  => 'Directions',
        'id'    => $prefix.'directions',
        'type'  => 'textarea'
    )
```

==========================

```
case 'textarea':
    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
```

How do i add wp_editor? I tried:

```
wp_editor( $content, 'recipe_directions', array( 'textarea_name' => 'recipe_directions', 'media_buttons' => false, 'tinymce' => array() ) );
```

But it doesn't work still showing regular field. Can anyone help.
The whole idea is to make regular textarea like rich text editor

Thanks for your help .... anyone:)

Comment: what do you mean by "no luck" ?

Comment: i mean it doesn't work for me, still showing regular field, no editor

Comment: is anyone here can help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case 'textarea':
wp_editor($meta, $field['id']);
echo '<br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
```

This is the way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

To use wp_editor() you'll need to replace your textarea tag with the output from wp_editor() like so:

```
case 'textarea':
    wp_editor($meta, $field['id']);
    echo '<br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
break;
```

You don't need to echo wp_editor() since it does it automatically. You can pass an array of settings as a 3rd argument to configure it's behaviour. More info here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out for you. Would you mind accepting the answer so I can get the reputation?